# Crystal Report, after saving the file, changes the filename to lowercase rather than UPPER case or Sensitive case as I entered

Tags: crystal-reports

Need help. Crystal Report changes the file name to lowercase after saving the file and not to UPPER case or Sensitive case as I entered. it always changes automatically.

How can this be? Can this be fixed?

Is there any way to fix this?or just coding?